# Laravel 5.3 - Auth Scaffolding How Are Errors Inserted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-facade, illuminate-container

Im relatively new to Laravel and try to make sense of something. I created a basic project and used `

` php artisan make:auth

` to generate a authentication scaffolding.

In the generated views, the $errors variable is available. I know that this can be inserted into a view by using the withErrors() method.

However, I can't seem to find how this is inserted in the example. Under the hood the following function seems to be handling registration:

```
    /**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

So the validator method of the default RegisterController is called, and it returns a validator. But i cannot grasp how the errors from the validator are inserted into the auth.register view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when a validation error occurs is that Laravel throws an exception. In this case an instance of `ValidationException` is thrown.

Laravel handles any uncaught exception using it's `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler` class. In your app you should see a class that extends it in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. In that class you will see that the `render` method calls it's parent's `render` method which if you check the code contains the following lines:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $e = $this->prepareException($e);

    if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
    }

    return $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
}
```

And if you check further in that same class, in the method `convertValidationExceptionToResponse` you can see that Laravel flashes the errors to the response and redirects back, with the input (When the request doesn't expect JSON):

```
protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
{
    if ($e->response) {
        return $e->response;
    }

    $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->input())->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RegisterController extends Controller, if we look at class Controller we can see use trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;`

If we look deeper, we find:

```
/**
     * Create the response for when a request fails validation.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  array  $errors
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                        ->withInput($request->input())
                        ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
    }
```